# RoR deploying DataTables to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Website works locally. When publishing to heroku get an error in the logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap'
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Essentially I had the gem in the assets group. As soon as I relocated it, the push to heroku worked.